# How to eliminate duplicate messages from command prompt while reading from inputstreams in java

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, simulator

I Reading an xml message from commnad prompt (Simulator) if i enter xml message and if it ends with >>> indicates end of message one i.e., when ever i press enter it invokes the server side thread and process the message . If i entered one more xml message gives enter i am getting both the first message and also last message but i dont want the first message so give me solution to eliminate it

The below code is inside of thread while(true) it will always listen the message and send it to the server while sending i want latest messages only.

```
while(true){
            if(clientsoc != null){
                tempchar=br.readLine();
                inputstring=inputstring+tempchar;
                if(inputstring.endsWith(">>>")){
                    inputstring=inputstring.replaceAll(">>>","");
                    serverstream.write(inputstring.getBytes());
                }
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                serverstream.close();
                serverstream = null;
                clientsoc.close();
                clientsoc = null;
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                clientsoc = null;
                serverstream = null;
            }
}   }
```

Comment: Clean up previous message by adding `inputstring ="";` after `serverstream.write(...);`?

Comment: I have done but it is not working

Comment: How does it misbehave exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you just want that when user enters a string like:

```
"message1>>>message2>>>"
```

this is what is sent to the server:

```
"message2"
```

In this case, a very simple condition check could be:

```
if (inputstring.endsWith(">>>")) {
    inputstring = inputstring.substring(0, inputstring.length()-3);
    int previousSeparatorIdx = inputstring.lastIndexOf(">>>");
    if (previousSeparatorIdx >= 0) {
        inputstring = inputstring.substring(previousSeparatorIdx+3);
    }
    serverstream.write(inputstring.getBytes());
}
```